# ¿se pueden crear varias tablas en una misma base de datos de SqLite? (Sqflite flutter)

Tags: sqlite, flutter, vscode, dart

No soy muy diestro en SqLite, según tengo entendido, de por sí en este lenguaje solo se puede crear una tabla al mismo tiempo, he estado buscando varios tutoriales en internet pero nada me queda claro, y casi todos solo crean una tabla para una base de datos; lo que necesito es crear una base de datos con varias tablas dentro de mi aplicación para utilizarlas más adelante, por ejemplo, una tabla para el login que almacene solamente el usuario, contraseña, id y nivel de admin, mientras que otra tabla se encargue de los empleados y de toda la información que puedan tener, la tabla nueva que quisiera crear debería verse algo así en SqLite:

```
db.execute("CREATE TABLE Usuario ("
            "id integer primary key,"
            "username TEXT,"
            "password TEXT,"
            "nivel TEXT,"
            ")");
          });
      }
```

Intento usar la aplicación de este [vídeo](https://youtu.be/sj9giQhnJec) pero no logro entender la sintaxis necesaria para crear una segunda, tercera, ... , n tablas en dicha base de datos, la probé y pude expandir la base de datos agregando mis propios atributos y renombrado unas cuantas variables, y todo funciona, pero necesito crear más tablas, ya que el modelo a introducir es muy grande, son al menos unos 80 atributos, y dudo que sea buena idea colocarlos todos dentro de una misma BD, o que de igual forma lo seria crear múltiples bases de datos, pero que cada una contenga una sola tabla, este es el código que estoy usando:

```
class ClientDatabaseProvider{
  ClientDatabaseProvider._();

  static final  ClientDatabaseProvider db = ClientDatabaseProvider._();
  Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if(_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await getDatabaseInstanace();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> getDatabaseInstanace() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, "Patrocinante.db");
      return await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Patrocinante ("
        "id integer primary key,"
        "name TEXT,"
        "phone TEXT,"
        "tipoindustria TEXT,"
        "nit TEXT,"
        "aliado TEXT,"
        "direccion TEXT,"
        "pais TEXT,"
        "estado TEXT,"
        "ciudad TEXT,"
        "codigopostal TEXT,"
        "email TEXT,"
        "paginaweb TEXT,"
        "bolsaempleo TEXT,"
        "referido TEXT,"
        "masinfo TEXT,"
        "exterior TEXT,"
        "phone2 TEXT"
        ")");
      });
  }
```

Si por favor pueden darme consejos sobre las estructuras o cualquier cosa sobre mi código o en general que deba ser modificado, es bien recibido, gracias de antemano.

Edit: Aquí esta el [proyecto](https://mega.nz/#!zoh2WSCT!XMcaVsgGG6mMhWXxSsNGrH5c8mAfFIyWzQY_iwJ_eEs) hasta ahora.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es si, sqlite y cualquier otro gestor de base de datos permite realizar varias consultas, creaciones, inserciones y otros de una sola vez, pero eso aveces te limita y puede desorganizar tu codigo. Por esa razon te recomiendo lo siguiente:

Si tienes varias tablas que crear cuando por ejemplo esta iniciando un proceso la app o que se yo haz algo parecido a esto:

```
String sql1 = "create bla bla bla;";
String sql2 = "create foo bar;";
String[] consultas = new String[]{sql1, sql2};

// then
for(String sql : consultas){
    database.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Cada consulta o creacion en un string de manera organizada y asi te evitas lios y lo mantienes con cierta estetica.

Ojo el codigo no es dart... es solo pseudocodigo.

Comment: Hey, no es una mala idea, creo haber visto como se pueden almacenar lineas de bases de datos dentro de un string en flutter, ahora solo resta investigar un poco y/o que alguien logre hacer eso adaptando mi código de arriba, ya que no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo según la sintaxis de dart.

Comment: @Squall32 pudiste lograrlo?

Answer (score 1):

```
String sql1 = "create bla bla bla;";
String sql2 = "create foo bar;";
String[] consultas = new String[]{sql1, sql2};

// then
for(String sql : consultas){
    database.execSQL(sql);
}
```

**ACORDE ESTA RESPUESTA**
**TU CODIGO QUEDARIA DE ESTA MANERA**

te proporciono el onCreate, hecho por mi por si acaso no habias podido hacerlo

```
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
           for (String query in queries) {
             await db.execute(query);
           }
       }
```